# Как присвоить метод конструктору?

Tags: javascript, конструктор

Я изучаю JS, и заметил что после создания объекта можно сделать внешнюю функцию его методом, при этом новый элемент внутри объекта (для хранения функции) создается прямо во время присваивания. Ели же мы хотим добавить функцию в конструктор, присвоить внешнюю функцию можно только уже существующему в конструкторе элементу.

**Вопрос - есть ли способ создать новый элемент в конструкторе после его создания** (и присвоить ему значение, например функцию)?

Вот пример. Если я правильно понимаю, `dog.newSound = changeSound;` работает потому что это объект а `animal.newSound = changeSound;` не рабоатет потому что это конструктор. Есть ли другой способ сделать то же самое для конструктора?

```js
//Конструктор

function Animal(name, age, sound) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sound = sound;
}

//внешняя функция
function changeSound(sound) {
  this.sound = sound;
}

//объект созданный с помощью конструктора
var dog = new Animal("Jack", 5, "gav-gav")

//создали переменную в объекте и присвоили ей функцию
dog.newSound = changeSound;
dog.newSound("woof-woof"); // вызвали функцию 

//пишем на страницу
var here = document.getElementById("placeHere");
here.innerHTML = dog.sound;
```

```html
<p id=placeHere></p>
```

Comment: конструирующие функции принято называть с большой буквы

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Спасибо большое, не знал!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `Animal.prototype` для добавления методов всем объектам типа `Animal`.

```js
//Конструктор

function Animal(name, age, sound) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sound = sound;
}

Animal.prototype.newSound = changeSound; // !!!
/* или без отдельной функции:
Animal.prototype.newSound = function (sound) {
  this.sound = sound;
}
*/

//внешняя функция
function changeSound(sound) {
  this.sound = sound;
}

//объект созданный с помощью конструктора
var dog = new Animal("Jack", 5, "gav-gav")

//создали переменную в объекте и присвоили ей функцию
//dog.newSound = changeSound;
dog.newSound("cock-a-doodle-doo"); // вызвали функцию 

//пишем на страницу
var here = document.getElementById("placeHere");
here.innerHTML = dog.sound;
```

```html
<p id=placeHere></p>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Если после `Animal.prototype` каким-либо способом посмотреть какие параметры имеет конструктор `Animal` - новая функция будет включена в конструктор? Или  `Animal.prototype` добавляет фцнкуию всем объектам созданным на основе конструктора но сам конструктор остается неизменным?

Comment: @Rumata Второе. Так, давайте определимся с терминологией. Параметры конструктора - `name, age, sound` - между круглых скобок. Свойства `this` никаким образом не обязаны отражать эти параметры. Свойств может быть меньше или больше, они могут называться совсем по-другому.

Comment: Спасибо, то есть свойства это внутренние переменные объекта, а параметры это конкретные значения которые мы им передаем при создании объекта, верно?

Comment: А первый вариант (модифицировать сам конструктор) - не возможно уже после его создания?

Comment: @Rumata Конструктор - это функция. Мы не создаем конструктор, мы вызываем функцию с `new`, чтобы создать новый объект. Свойства этого объекта, непосредственно после создания, определяются кодом внутри функции. Методы объекта могут быть определены внутри конструктора и/или используя прототип.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное объяснение, оно действительно помогает лучше понять что есть что. Тогда мой вопрос - можно ли изменить саму функцю извне? В данном случае - функцию конструктора.

Comment: Хотя наверное это уже новый вопрос :) Спасибо еще раз!